# Reasons why a handlebars will not load?

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

A rather peculiar question:

I have a website with a `views` directory that has a subdirectory `layouts` that contain the `main.handlebars` which has the line `{{{body}}}` in the body section of the html.

Now in the `views` directory, I have 25 `.handlebars` file with all different names and same content. But for some reason, one of the `.handlebars` file which is named `character-info.handlebars` does not load, when all other handlebars load without issues.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. changing the name of the `.handlebars` file.
2. inputting just the line `<h1>Hello</h1>` in the file.
3. Deleting the file and remaking the file.
4. Manually entering the handlebars address i.e. `http://localhost:3000/character-info`

But none of it seems to work...
Is there a limit to the total number of handlebars that are allowed in a webpage? If not, what else would be the issue here?

Comment: on the event that should load that handlebar file are you noticing any errors or irregularities in your console log?